# What can be reason I got CORS error but it was actually NOT a CORS error (more like a 504)?

Tags: php, cors, http-status-code-504

What can be reason I got CORS error but it was actually NOT a CORS error? Please refer to the following pictures to see what I mean:

The console output the error that the request has been blocked by CORS policy:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[image: CORS error]

BUT actually that was not the case. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is in response header.

[image: CORS]

This is because the php code writes,
`$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $request->server('HTTP_ORIGIN'));` which is basically the same as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

But for that error request, the response is, i.e. no response.

[image: CORS error2]

The reason is actually the php process was hang by `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory  exhausted`

[image: PHP Fatal error]

I had assumed in this case I would got a [504](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504) Gateway timeout, i.e. no response from upstream. But why did console output CORS error instead?

Comment: looks similar to this problem. https://peng.fyi/post/cors-error-with-504/

Comment: Actually I feel the article may not be correct as it said "If possible, make requests qualify simple request. This **reduces the preflight requests**." As for as I know preflight request is always send for non-get request for CORS.

Comment: if the request qualify as "simple request", then the preflight request is not sent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests
A POST can be simple. A GET may be not simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking into successful response from server that do contains correct CORS header.

Check headers of failed request. Since it's internal PHP error (reached memory limit) your code that adds CORS is never reached.

---

So in the end:

1. Server fails to add CORS headers on 5XX error
2. Browser blocks response processing because of missing CORS

Comment: Thanks. So I should just add `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";` in my nginx.conf instead doing that in my php codes, right?

Comment: Yes, if you allow any origin. If it's pre-defined list of origins, then you must rely on other ways